# Problem with missing values in cluster id column

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, outliers, dbscan

i was looking for some help regarding how i can add a column in my df that contains the cluster id (used algorith to cluster dataset is DBSCAN, i tried the following

```
# Compute DBSCAN

db = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=30, algorithm='kd_tree', n_jobs=-1).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
np.sum(labels)
# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_clusters_
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))
    df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(labels))
    df = df.rename(columns={0:'Cluster'})
    df.head
```

but i have a problem that does not seem logical.Before the clustering my datasaet had no missing values, whereas , when i add the column(Cluster),clsuter=-1 is for noise etc, i get missing values too(!),so when i try to clean my dataset i do not have any option rather than exlcude cluster=-1 and missing values too,something that i do not want .Can you please help me with my issue?

You can find attached the output that contains the problem .
There are about 3000 missing values in the column of clustering and i don' t understand how that happened.

The dataset's columns before the entry of extra column had 38037 rows .

Any comment would be helpful.

Thank you

[Problem with missing values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhuBA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something have been happened with indices in your `df`. As you can read in Pandas `join` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), if parameter `on` have not been specified:

> Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, otherwise joins index-on-index.

So, something like this is happening:

```
labels
Out[66]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1, -1], dtype=int64)

# make dataframe that exactly matches labels
df = pd.DataFrame(labels, columns=['a'])

df
Out[68]: 
   a
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
5 -1

# change indices
df = df.set_index([pd.Index([0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8])])

df
Out[70]: 
   a
0  0
1  0
3  0
5  1
7  1
8 -1

df.join(pd.DataFrame(labels))
Out[71]: 
   a    0
0  0  0.0
1  0  0.0
3  0  1.0
5  1 -1.0
7  1  NaN
8 -1  NaN
```

I'd suggest to reset indices before DBSCAN if you don't need current indices: `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code is causing the missing values:

> df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(labels))

**Explanation:**

`pandas.DataFrame.join()` joins DataFrame objects by index. The "df" DataFrame has an Int64Index with values ranging from 0 to 41187, but only 38037 entries - that means the index values are not consecutive but contain gaps, probably from removing/filtering rows after the dataframe was created and before your code snippet was executed.

The DataFrame containing the labels you create with `pd.DataFrame(labels)` will have its own index, with values ranging from 0 to 38037. If this DataFrame is joined with the original DataFrame, the resulting DataFrame will only contain rows where the index values of your original DataFrame and the label DataFrame match, and due to the gaps in your original DataFrame's index, this is only the case for 35246 rows.

The easiest solution is to reindex the original DataFrame so it contains consecutive index values again:

> df = df.reset_index(drop=True).join(pd.DataFrame(labels))

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.It seems to work!Just to have a better understanding and since i am making th first steps in Pyhton and generally Data science,in this particular case ia was asked to cluster the data and then remov the outliers that occurs.Then,i have to compare the accuracy,f-score etc regarding the efficiency of the algorithm.The point here is to evaluate the impact of outliers in algorithm's efficiency.

Comment: As i undrstand i did exclude a number of rows from my df as a result of preprocessing but i did not drop them .Is this going to affect the efficiency of DBSCAN the first time i run(before the outlier detection) or is this happening when i am trying to add the column with cluster id in my original df?